# Given a string(e.g "hello world!"), a fontface(e.g Arial), a display length(e.g 1 inch), how to calculate the actual font size?

Tags: fonts, truetype

I have tried the following method:
Since the string and the display length are given, and we can get every char's designed width from the fontface's ttf file(advance width in hmtx table), if we konw a char's designed height, then we can get the actual font size. The problem is i could not find the char's actual height, i have tried to use the subtraction of yMax and yMin in char's glyf table, but the calculated font size is a bit small. So, how can i get the actual fontface's designed height? Any reply is welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "actual size".

Comment: actual size means the font size that makes the string fits the display length.